# Does any C/C++ compiler support OpenMP's task affinity clauses yet?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, task, openmp

I am experimenting with OpenMP tasks and want to write an application that runs on a 2-NUMA socket CPU and uses OpenMP's task affinity clauses which can be added to the task creation pragma. They provide a hint for where a task should be executed, by providing a variable close to whose physical location the task should be executed.

An example from the OpenMP 5.0 documentation shows how it could be used:

```
void task_affinity(double *A, int N)
{
 double * B;
 #pragma omp task depend(out:B) shared(B) affinity(A[0:N])
 {
 B = alloc_init_B(A,N);
 }

 #pragma omp task depend( in:B) shared(B) affinity(A[0:N])
 {
 compute_on_B(B,N);
 }

 #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

The compiler gcc compiler that I have in version 11.2.0, however, only provides a stub as of now, which as I understand it, means, that the functionality is not actually implemented yet.

1. Is there any compiler that has OpenMP's task affinities fully implemented yet?
2. Does the gcc implementation of OpenMP handle tasks in a way that they are assigned to threads that are physically close to the data on which they work even if no affinities are explicitly stated?

Comment: FWIW: https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/

Comment: GCC is notoriously bad at task placement. I would use a different compiler.

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is that if you initialize an array from a single thread, then that array will wind up on the memory associated with the socket of that thread. That's called "first touch". So you want to always initialize arrays in parallel, unless you really want them to be Non-Uniform addressable.

Comment: If you use clang and check the assembly, there is a function call to `__kmpc_omp_reg_task_with_affinity@PLT`, so most probably it does support it.

Comment: As far as I remember it is an OpenMP 5.0 feature and gcc supports 4.5 only. I actually got an error compiling the code above in gcc 11.2.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout The data initialization is already handled in the way you suggested, however, the bad task placement in gcc is new to me. Does that also extend to other task based parallel runtimes like tbb? Are there any resources on this that I could look into as it would relate to my course project at university.

Comment: @Laci It works with clang, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Using tbb makes no difference as long as you keep using the gnu runtime library. Different thread libraries probably use the same underlying mechanism. Switch compilers. And since you are now using clang apparently, do a comparative study: track what thread the tasks run on and see if there is an even distribution.